# Issue in Chrome browser when select's option is removed with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, select

I have the following HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Remove Me</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="5">Test 5</option>
</select>
```

And I want when the user click on the select, the option with value '0' to be removed. This is the jQuery script I am using:

```
$('select').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('option[value="0"]').remove();
});
```

This is working in Firefox and IE(10,9,8) but in Chrome, when the option is removed, the last one is duplicated like this:

[image]

If I click on the select again, when it expands, the duplicated option is gone.
Why this is not working in the first place like in FireFox?

This is fidle of my issue - http://jsfiddle.net/FN5jL/1/

Comment: I cannot reproduce ( chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: I am testing this on Windows 8 and Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m ...

Comment: Happend the same thing for me (29.0.1547.49 (Officiell version 216092) beta-m) windows 7

Comment: I have Chrome 30.0.1588.0 (Dev version latest) and the same happens. so maybe no fix expected soon :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FN5jL/3/)

```
$('select').one('focus',function(){
    $(this).find('option[value="0"]').remove();
});
```

I don't know where this strange behaviour comes from...